# netty: redirecting requests with serialization inbetween

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I'm building a proxy with two endpoints and with a custom protocol in between.
Means, I'll receive the original request on one site, serialize it for the custom protocol, de-serialize it on the other end and send it to a defined target server. Same back with the response.

The thing looks about like this:
[image]

This all works wonderful. The thing is, that the custom protocol in the middle has a max size of about 5 MB. Although I need to be able to post files bigger than this.

I now had an idea, which I'm not sure if it is possible and I would be very happy about some advice.

Right now, I'm collecting all the HttpObjects and send the whole request at once over the custom protocol. On the other end, I'm parsing a FullHttpRequest, modify the Host, URI and so one and send it to the target server. Here again, same procedure with the response. This is of course a waste of memory and time.

Now with this I'm not sure:
I could immediately send all the HttpObjects that I receive, over the custom protocol without collecting the whole request first and send it in a whole.
On the other end, I still could manipulate the one HttpRequest object and the just pump all the HttpObjects, one after the other, into the outgoing channel until the HttpLastContent object. Would this work?
I thought I'd rather ask first, before putting too much effort in it just to find out it's a stupid idea.

Comment: what was the result?

Comment: @mjallday I'm afraid that I don't have access to the project anymore. As far as I remember I ended up opening a response stream and feeding it packet by packet which just worked fine.